# Python nmap - PortScannerAsync(), cannot trap callback function data globally

Tags: python-3.x, nmap, asynchronous

I am using the `nma = nmap.PortScannerAsync()`

from `nma.scan(target, port, arguments='-A', callback=callback_p)`

From the function `callback_p()` I can print each return without difficulty, what I cannot seem to do it trap each globally.

Globally I declared a dictionary `data_dict = dict()`

```
def callback_p(host, result):
    global data_dict
    print('---')
    print(host, result)
    print('---')
    data_dict[host] = result
```

However, the `data_dict` stubbornly remains empty. I have even declared it as a `global` variable within the function but alas no avail. Surely there is a way to trap the asynchronous data and use it globally after the `nma.still_scanning() == False`?

**Code**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
''' NMAP Asynchronous Scan '''

import sys
import nmap

target = '192.168.0.10-12'
port = '22-1024'
data_dict = dict()

def callback_p(host, result):
    ''' Callback Printer '''
    global data_dict
    print('\n---')
    print(host, result)
    data_dict[host] = result
    return 0

# // Create an NMAP object //
nma = nmap.PortScannerAsync()

# // Asynchronous scan and callback as results come in //
nma.scan(target, port, arguments='-A', callback=callback_p)

#// Print dots to indicate program is working //
while nma.still_scanning():
    print('.', end=' ', flush=True)
    nma.wait(1)

# // Print dictionary output //
print()
print('data_dict', data_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out, for a multithreaded application you cannot use a global dictionary. What is required is a `DictProxy` which is a manager object returned by `multiprocess.Manager()`. This is a Python object that allows other processes to manipulate it using proxies. In other words, each thread as well as the main program can manipulate the object and when the threads are complete it is a simple matter of changing the `DictProxy` to a `dict()` before further processing.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
''' NMAP Asynchronous Scan '''

import sys
import nmap
from multiprocessing import Manager   # Import Manager

target = '192.168.0.10-12'
port = '22-1024'
data_dict = Manager().dict()          # Create DictProxy

def callback_p(host, result):
    ''' Callback Printer '''
    print('\n---')
    print(host, result)
    data_dict[host] = result          # Use like it is a standard dict
    return 0

# // Create an NMAP object //
nma = nmap.PortScannerAsync()

# // Asynchronous scan and callback as results come in //
nma.scan(target, port, arguments='-A', callback=callback_p)

#// Print dots to indicate program is working //
while nma.still_scanning():
    print('.', end=' ', flush=True)
    nma.wait(1)

# // Print dictionary output //
print()
print('data_dict', dict(data_dict))     # Convert to a dict()
```